# How to resolve Attempt to de-reference a null object in Apex Controller

Tags: apex, null-pointer

I am trying to bind my map value to wrapper class in apex controller . I am getting `System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object`. I couldn't understand where I am going wrong. Any help highly appreciated.

**Wrapper Class**

```
public class SetOrder {

        public String OrderNumber{get;set;}
        public List<Item> Items{get;set;}

    public class Item{

        public Integer Quantity{get;set;}
        public Integer Id{get;set;}
    }
}
```

**Apex Controller**

```
String return = {"name":"test-0","OrderNumber":"OG00000002","Quantity":1,"Id":11,"Returndate":null};
  Map<String,Object> prod = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(return);
           SetOrder obj = new SetOrder();
           obj.OrderNumber = String.valueOf(prod.get('OrderNumber')); 
           obj.Items[0].Quantity = Integer.valueOf(prod.get('Quantity'));
           obj.Items[0].Id = Integer.valueOf(prod.get('Id'));
```

Comment: The String return = {"name":"test-0","OrderNumber":"OG00000002","Quantity":1,"Id":11,"Returndate":null};` should be `String return = '{"name":"test-0","OrderNumber":"OG00000002","Quantity":1,"Id":11,"Returndate":null}';`

Comment: @NoorAShuvo the problem is when I remove the following code its not showing any error `obj.Items[0].Quantity = Integer.valueOf(prod.get('Quantity'));
           obj.Items[0].Id = Integer.valueOf(prod.get('Id'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize an object such as a list or map before you can use it:

```
obj.Items = new List<Item>();
```

You'll also need to add a new Item to the list:

```
obj.Items.add(new Item());
```

---

```
String jsonString = {"name":"test-0","OrderNumber":"OG00000002","Quantity":1,"Id":11,"Returndate":null};
  Map<String,Object> prod = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);
           SetOrder obj = new SetOrder();
           obj.OrderNumber = String.valueOf(prod.get('OrderNumber')); 
           obj.Items = new List<Item>();
           obj.Items.add(new Item());
           obj.Items[0].Quantity = Integer.valueOf(prod.get('Quantity'));
           obj.Items[0].Id = Integer.valueOf(prod.get('Id'));
```